# Is there a way to change folder permissions from PHP without using FTP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to change folder permissions from PHP without using FTP?
I'm creating new folders on server automatically, but i cannot move the uploaded file in it because of the folder permissions. Do you have any idea that I can change the permission of the folder without using FTP?

Comment: FYI, if you search the online PHP docs for ["change file permissions"](http://us2.php.net/results.php?q=change%2Bfile%2Bpermissions&l=en&p=wholesite), you quickly find all of the PHP functions related to getting and setting permissions. I personally have that search tool installed in Firefox with a keyword saved for it. This way, I can type `php {my query}` and easily search the documentation. Most of the time, that's all it takes to find out how to perform basic tasks in PHP. It's also great for looking up the syntax/argument list of a function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
chmod('/home/path/directory/', 0777)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php