# Using a text files to store data

Tags: php

I want to to read and write some data to text files from my PHP app.  Its a small amount of data. Really just configurations.

My concern is that I have no control over the deployment environment. It will be a mixed bag of servers, mac and windows. They will all be running PHP5.3 and greater.  The mac servers will have apache, and the windows servers will be running IIS.

I don't want customers calling with issues related to server setup and or permissions on files/folders.

I am pretty sure that WordPress does this all the time so, I know this is possible to do cleanly.  The questions is how?  Does anyone have any suggestions, pointers to libraries, or strategies that will help me accomplish my goal.

I ruled out sqlLite for this purpose, because i don't think it is enabled by default on windows and I think it is no longer installed on php5.4 windows by default.  My main goal is to be able to persist a small amount of data in such a way that does drive my support costs through the rough the roof.

Comment: Can you explain which configuration details in a PHP world care about what kind of OS the user is using?

Comment: this might help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125523/is-there-a-way-to-change-folder-permissions-from-php-without-using-ftp

Comment: @kaiQing I am assuming its the folder where his text file will sit might not have write permissions on so writing config to it will crash the system

Comment: If I'm not mistaken many setup permissions with FTP commands in their install script using the PHP FTP library http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php.  You will also want to lock and unlock the file when writing.

Comment: @MadDok - yeah but CMS packages like drupal straight up tell you on installation that the expected directory does not have write permissions. So just use a function like is_writable() to verify on install.

Comment: yes I can test to see if the directory is writable. That isn't a problem. The problem is the user will still call me and ask me how to fix it. Thats the part I want to avoid :-)

Comment: You can't avoid that, it's a base law of technology: ***"As soon as you make something idiot-proof, nature will invent a better idiot"***. All you can do is make it less likely, by providing good tutorials and clear errors.

Answer (score 1):

The way all common big PHP projects do it afaik is simply by reserving a folder for it, and checking its permissions on install.

You could easily make a `/gen` or `/data` folder in your webroot, and on install/update check that it:

1. contains a `.htaccess` file stating `deny from all` if the webserver is Apache, or an equivalent method of protection (just `file_get_contents` via the public URL to test) on other webservers
2. [`is_writable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) (you could also write, read and delete a small sample file to ensure this)

Put your documents in there and it's safe and portable on every platform.

Some sample code:

```
$docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$dataroot = $docroot.'/data';
$testfile = $dataroot.'/test.txt';
$publicURL = $youHaveThisSomewhere.'/data/test.txt';
if(!is_dir($dataroot))
  die("The required data folder is not present at $dataroot");
if(!is_writable($dataroot) || file_put_contents($testfile, 'test') === FALSE)
  die("Data path ($dataroot) is not writable, make it so!");
if(file_get_contents($publicURL) !== FALSE)
  die("Data path is publicly accessible, go fix it!");
if(!unlink($testfile))
  die("I also need delete rights in the data folder!");

die("Installation successful!");
```

Comment: For IIS you would need a web.config file instead of .htaccess.

Comment: @toddgeist no it does not, but MS has a guide to convert .htaccess files to web.config.

Comment: @toddgeist In IIS you can easily import all (most) rewrite rules automatically. (Which is not very important for this case.)

Comment: does web.config go in the folder?  ie can I install it? or is it something that has to be done to the IIS configuration. Because if so then that is out.  I can't assume that the users will be able to do that.

Comment: @toddgeist seems like you can place it in any directory from http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5445/what-is-a-webconfig-file.

Comment: @toddgeist you can definitely assume a user that can INSTALL a webapp is able to perform base maintenance. Just test by public URL whether the directory is secured, and if not throw a hard blocking error. Put a link in there to a step-by-step document explaining the process.

Comment: web.config is for IIS what .htaccess is for Apache. It will not help you much. It does not make files/directories writable and it is not itsself writable by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but even with Wordpress you have to worry about making certain files and directories writable (chmod, windows file permissions, etc).

And if I'm not mistaking Joomla/Wordpress (one of them at least) also give you the opportunity to enter FTP credentials, so rather than editing the file through the filesystem, it will try to upload the edited version through the FTP server.

What you simply could do is have a config file that must be edited in a text editor. And have the text-file read only for the webserver / application. But then changing one of these setting cannot be done through the website itsself, but needs a person to edit the text file in a text editor.

If you are already using a database, then ONLY the database-settings would have to be in the config file. The rest can be stored in the database.

Comment: there is no database here other than this little TextFile :-)

Comment: Then I'd think your best thing is to still help people understand how to make a specific directory writable. Maybe even make 3 small youtube movies: win, mac, linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option you may be looking for involves the following steps:

Create an install file in this install script file:

1. See if directory is writable
2. If not ask for FTP credentials
3. Determine the system type Windows or *Nix bassed
4. Establish an FTP connection
5. *nix variants send a CHMOD command Windows send a CACLS command to make the directory writable
6. Terminate the FTP command